# Can emacs re-indent a big blob of HTML for me?

Tags: html, emacs

When editing HTML in emacs, is there a way to automatically pretty-format a blob of markup, changing something like this:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
<td>blah</td></tr></table>
```

...into this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   blah
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a lot easier in newer versions of emacs. This is a scroll-down situation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, when you visit a `.html` file in Emacs (22 or 23), it will put you in `html-mode`.  That is probably not what you want.  You probably want `nxml-mode`, which is seriously fancy. `nxml-mode` seems to only come with Emacs 23, although you can download it for earlier versions of emacs from the [nXML web site](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/).  There is also a Debian and Ubuntu package named `nxml-mode`.  You can enter `nxml-mode` with:

```
M-x nxml-mode
```

You can view nxml mode documentation with:

```
C-h i g (nxml-mode) RET
```

All that being said, you will probably have to use something like [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to re-format your xhtml example.  `nxml-mode` will get you from

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
<td>blah</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
    <td>blah</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

but I don't see a more general facility to do line breaks on certain xml tags as you want.  Note that `C-j` will insert a new line with proper indentation, so you may be able to do a quick macro or hack up a `defun` that will do your tables.

Comment: After I enter nxml-mode, I use C-x h to select the whole region, then M-x 'indent-region'. You will get correctly indented HTML. Thanks to nxml-mode!

Comment: nxml-mode doesn't indent properly for html fragments, probably because they don't have a doctype. html-mode works fine once you get the line breaks in as suggested by @nevcx below

Answer (score 123):

You can do `sgml-pretty-print` and then `indent-for-tab` on the same region/buffer, provided you are in html-mode or nxml-mode.

`sgml-pretty-print` adds new lines to proper places and `indent-for-tab` adds nice indentation. Together they lead to properly formatted html/xml.

Comment: Great answer. Just remember to temporarily switch to sgml-mode to run sgml-pretty-print. Then go back to nxml-mode.

Comment: `sgml-pretty-print` worked for me from HTML wode without any mode switching, thanks!

Comment: The only answer that really works. I mean even on invalid XML (i.e. just a part of HTML file).

Answer (score 14):

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_277.html

After selecting the region you want to fix. (To select the whole buffer use C-x h)

> *C-M-q*
>
> Reindent all the lines within one parenthetical grouping(indent-sexp).
>
> *C-M-\*
>
> Reindent all lines in the region (indent-region).

Comment: That doesn't work for me -- on the example above, C-M-q does nothing, and C-M-\ gives a completely incorrect indenting.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me in nxml mode.  index-sexp and indent-region will indent code that already has line breaks, this example is missing a few.

Comment: C-X h <ESC> x indent-region

Answer (score 10):

i wrote a function myself to do this for xml, which works well in nxml-mode.  should work pretty well for html as well:

```
(defun jta-reformat-xml ()
  "Reformats xml to make it readable (respects current selection)."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((beg (point-min))
          (end (point-max)))
      (if (and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
          (progn
            (setq beg (min (point) (mark)))
            (setq end (max (point) (mark))))
        (widen))
      (setq end (copy-marker end t))
      (goto-char beg)
      (while (re-search-forward ">\\s-*<" end t)
        (replace-match ">\n<" t t))
      (goto-char beg)
      (indent-region beg end nil))))
```

Comment: This is actually the simplest and best solution.  I'm going to use this often!  Thank you!!!

Comment: works for me. feels like the least complex solution too. ta very muchly

Answer (score 10):

In emacs 25, which I'm currently building from source, assuming you are in HTML mode, use
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>
<kbd>h</kbd>

to select all, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

This question is quite old, but I wasn't really happy with the various answers. A simple way to re-indent an HTML file, given that you are running a relatively newer version of emacs (I am running 24.4.1) is to:

- open the file in emacs
- mark the entire file with `C-x h` (note: if you would like to see what is being marked, add `(setq transient-mark-mode t)` to your `.emacs` file)
- execute `M-x indent-region`

What's nice about this method is that it does not require any plugins (Conway's suggestion), it does not require a replace regexp (nevcx's suggestion), nor does it require switching modes (jfm3's suggestion). Jay's suggestion is in the right direction — in general, executing `C-M-q` will indent according to a mode's rules — for example, `C-M-q` works, in my experience, in `js-mode` and in several other modes. But neither `html-mode` nor `nxml-mode` do not seem to implement `C-M-q`.

Comment: Great answer. Two lines. Done all the job perfectly!

Comment: Follow up question, your solution won't indent the javascript in the html. Do you have any easy and fast solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: This works if the line breaks are already in the right places. sgml-pretty-print helps with that (but in my view, still not making the best choices).

Answer (score 8):

You can do a replace regexp

```
 M-x replace-regexp

 \(</[^>]+>\)

 \1C-q-j
```

Indent the whole buffer

```
 C-x h
 M-x indent-region
```

Answer (score 6):

[Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) can do what you want, but only for whole buffer it seems (and the result is XHTML)

```
M-x tidy-buffer
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe a region to xmllint (if you have it) using:

```
M-|
Shell command on region: xmllint --format -
```

The result will end up in a new buffer.

I do this with XML, and it works, though I believe xmllint needs certain other options to work with HTML or other not-perfect XML.  nxml-mode will tell you if you have a well-formed document.

Comment: And with a prefix argument, `shell-command-on-region` replaces the original region with the shell command's output. i.e.: `C-u M-|`

Comment: Thanks, phils, I knew that feature was there, but couldn't remember how to invoke it!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is via command line.

- Make sure you have tidy installed
- type `tidy -i -m <<file_name>>`

Note that `-m` option replaces the newly tidied file with the old one. If you don't want that, you can type `tidy -i -o <<tidied_file_name>> <<untidied_file_name>>`

The `-i` is for indentation. Alternatively, you can create a `.tidyrc` file that has settings such as

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
wrap: 72
markup: yes
output-xml: no
input-xml: no
show-warnings: yes
numeric-entities: yes
quote-marks: yes
quote-nbsp: yes
quote-ampersand: no
break-before-br: no
uppercase-tags: no
uppercase-attributes: no
```

This way all you have to do is type `tidy -o <<tidied_file_name>> <<untidied_file_name>>`.

For more just type `man tidy` on the command line.

Comment: Afaiu, this is called from the shell. I think he wants a solution within emacs.