# HTML Tags in Emacs not Aligning

Tags: html, emacs, indentation

I'm using the shipped HTML mode with Emacs and writing a basic index.html page (eg. just a body with a div inside).  When I try to close a tag, Emacs doesn't auto-indent the tag to match the opening tag.  Do I have to set something in my .emacs file?

The problem is thus:

```
<div>
    content....
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to close a tag?

Comment: Yeah, it's prevalent in even the sparsest (and correct-est...) of HTML files.

Comment: Always describe a detailed repro starting with `emacs -Q`.  Otherwise we can't know what you've done to bork your environment.  Emacs indents HTML very well out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resorted to running `C-M-\` to auto-format my code once I've typed it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be similar to what you're after:

[Can't change Emacs's default indentation between HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076783/cant-change-emacss-default-indentation-between-html-tags)

More info on HTML indentation:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingHtml

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    ;; Default indentation is usually 2 spaces, changing to 4.
    (set (make-local-variable 'sgml-basic-offset) 4)))
```

**Edit**:

This seems like it might be a good solution: [Can emacs re-indent a big blob of HTML for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137043/can-emacs-re-indent-a-big-blob-of-html-for-me)

> By default, when you visit a .html file in Emacs (22 or 23), it will
>   put you in html-mode. That is probably not what you want. You probably
>   want nxml-mode, which is seriously fancy. nxml-mode seems to only come
>   with Emacs 23, although you can download it for earlier versions of
>   emacs from the nXML web site. There is also a Debian and Ubuntu
>   package named nxml-mode

Comment: I actually have that in my emacs file already - it simply increases the indentation of a tab.  So pressing tab indents a bit further than it would before.

But I'm actually looking for something to line up both tags.